# How Do I 'Break' this Inequality?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am trying to show that $d(x,y) = e^{|x-y|} - 1$ does not define a metric on $\Bbb{R}$, but I am having some difficulty. I have already shown that it satisfies every property of a metric except the triangle inequality. So, what I am trying to do is 'break' 
the following inequality:

$$e^{|x-y|} + 1 \le e^{|x-z|} + e^{|z-y|}$$

I have tried several ways of breaking this inequality (e.g., reducing the number of variables and then trying to show a certain function is negative), but I have failed. I could use a hint.

Answer (score 2):

Take $z=0$ and $x=\ln(3/2)$, $y=\ln(3/4)$,
$$3=2+1=e^{\ln(2)} + 1=e^{|x-y|} + 1 \le e^{|x-z|} + e^{|z-y|}= e^{|\ln(3/2)|} + e^{|\ln(3/4)|}=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{4}{3}=\frac{17}{6}$$
which is not true (no need of a calculator here).

Hence the triangle inequality does not hold and $d(x,y) = e^{|x-y|} - 1$ is not a valid metric in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting $x = 0, y = 20, z = 10$, we get
$$
e^{20} + 1 \leq e^{10} + e^{10}
$$
which just isn't true.

Comment: Is there a quick way of seeing this without using a calculator?

Comment: @user193319 $$e^{20} = (e^{10})^2 = e^{10}\cdot e^{10}>2^{10}\cdot e^{10} = 1024\cdot e^{10} > 2\cdot e^{10}-1$$So it's true by a wide margin, which is why I chose $20$ and $10$. In fact, $e^2 > e^1 + e^1 - 1$ by more or less the same argument, so I could've chosen $x = 0, y = 2, x = 1$. I just chose those values because I didn't want to have to actually check before posting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the triangle law to fail, you need merely a single instance where it does not hold.

Typically for this sort of thing, one can find such an instance simply by picking values and plugging them in. Often, random unenlightened choices suffice. Sometimes you need to take a little bit of care to avoid consistently picking special values for which it does hold, and occasionally you need more intelligent analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we did have
$$ e^{|x-y|} + 1 \overset{?}{≤}  e^{|x-z|} + e^{|z-y|}.$$
Take $y=0$, $x>0$, and $0<z<x$:
$$ e^{x} + 1 \overset{?}{≤}  e^{x-z} + e^{z}.$$
The inequality has no $z$ on the left; minimising in $z$ the right hand side leads us to see $x = 2z$ so that

$$e^{2z} + 1 \overset{?}{≤} 2e^z.$$

Take $z→∞$ to see a contradiction.